# Regexp: Replacing stings that looks like Something(value) with value

Tags: php

I have the following file let us supposed to name it `dummyFile.txt`:

```
{
  v1: SuperHero("Superman")
},
{
  v1: Number(2)
},
{
  v1: BadWord("f**")
}
```

And I want to transform into:

```
{
  v1: "Superman"
},
{
  v1: 2
},
{
  v1: "f**"
}
```

So far I tried this script:

```php
 $contents=file_get_contents('./dummyFile.txt');
 $replace=preg_replace('/ \s+\( | \) /',"",$contents);
 var_dump($replace);
 echo "\n";
```

But I get the output:

```
{
  v1: SuperHero("Superman")
},
{
  v1: Number(2)
},
{
  v1: BadWord("f**")
}
```

Which is exactly the same with the input. I also tried to replace the following line:

```
 $replace=preg_replace('/ \s+\( | \) /',"",$contents);
```

With:

```
$replace=preg_replace('/ (SuperHero|Number|BadWord)\( | \) /',"",$contents);
```

With the same result. Do you fellows have any Idea how to solve it?

## Edit 1:

Also the following regex does not work: (for reference only)

```
$replace=preg_replace('/\w+\( | \) /',"",$contents);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `preg_replace('/\w+\((.*?)\)/', '$1', $contents)` for your `preg_replace`.

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/pQB1MF/1)

You were using `\s+` to match `SuperHero`, but you should use `\w+` which matches letters, whereas `\s` matches whitespace.

Comment: It worked but I cannot understand why. Can you explain it a bit further. I mean how does preg_replace understands that $1 is the value I want?

Comment: @DimitriosDesyllas The open brackets `()` in regex signifies a capture group, which stuffs everything inside the brackets into the `$1` variable. See https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html for more info. Also see the regex101 demo for a full explanation of the regex.